# Jmeter how to get value of Httprequest GET at runtime

Tags: jmeter

I have done lot of cases where value is extracted from response of first request  and passed to the subsequent request using Regular expression/CSS extractor etc but now i want to extract a value at GET and pass it to same GET (When i click on my page a random code is generated which has to be passed to the same page, this code will be unique for every click). How i can create as a variable and store value of code and pass ?

how to extract GET value from request in jmeter at runtime and pass it as variable. i want to pass this value as variable in same request
See below screenshot

[image]

My C# code for encrytion/decrytion is as follows -

```
 string handlerPath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(appPath + "/ReportFileUpload.ashx");

            string cipherText = string.Empty;
            string passPhrase = "!MMFileUploader123";        // can be any string
            string initVector = "2038459710286532"; // must be 16 bytes

            // Before encrypting data, we will append plain text to a random
            // salt value, which will be between 4 and 8 bytes long (implicitly
            // used defaults).
            RijndaelEnhanced cipher = new RijndaelEnhanced(passPhrase, initVector); //, 4, 16, 256, "SHA1", DateTime.Today.ToBinary().ToString());

            cipherText = cipher.Encrypt("?rn=" + repNum + "&uid=" + user.UserId + "&op=" + originPath + "&hp=" + handlerPath + "&p=" + pass + "&domain=" + domain + "&org=" + org + "&entitytype=" + entityType);
            cipherText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cipherText);
```

//Decrypt

//decipher the code get the parameters and assign them to inParams

```
      string passPhrase = "!MMFileUploader123";
                string initVector = "2038459710286532"; // must be 16 bytes

                RijndaelEnhanced cipher = new RijndaelEnhanced(passPhrase, initVector);
string cipherText = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(
                                ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query)["code"];

                            inParams = cipher.Decrypt(cipherText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a pre-generated `random code` stored in CSV (CSV Data Set Config) and pass it to the request.

Ask your developer about the logic to generate the `random code`, it should be similar to some md5 encryption.

Comment: Why can’t I read the code which is generating at runtime and pass ?? I don’t want to create and store

Comment: Because it seems you're random code is not generated at server side, the code is being generated on client itself through javascript which cannot be capture by Jmeter, To avoid using CSV config you can use function available in Jmeter 5 `${__digest(SHA-256,String to be hashed,Salt,,)}`, but in order to have the correct code which gets validated at server side, you need to know the encryption logic for generating valid random code.

Comment: My code is not generated using JS. I have got my code for encryption/decryption but i am not sure how to use it in Jmeter. I am posting code above in the post. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use JSR223 Pre processor to generate random value before your request and pass that value to your request.